# Superconformal transformation (Polchinski text 12.3.8)

Tags: differential-geometry, string-theory, fermions, superconformality

I am reading Polchinski's text book STING THEORY.
In the above of eq.(12.3.8), the differential $D_\theta = \partial_\theta + \theta\partial_z$ is defined and
\begin{equation}
D_\theta = D_\theta\theta'\partial_{\theta'}
 + D_\theta z'\partial_{z'}
 + D_\theta\bar\theta'\partial_{\bar\theta'}
 + D_\theta\bar z'\partial_{\bar z'}.
\end{equation}
I think it is given by the chain rule.
Next by using the property that superconformal transformation changes $D_\theta$ into a multiple of itself, he derives $D_\theta\bar\theta' = D_\theta z' = 0$ and $D_\theta z' = \theta'D_\theta\theta'$. So $D_\theta = (D_\theta\theta')D_{\theta'}$.

Next he says $D_\theta^2 = \partial_z$ (I could prove it) and using it,
\begin{equation}
\partial_{\bar z}z' = \partial_{\bar\theta}z' = \partial_{\bar z}\theta' = \partial_{\bar\theta}\theta' = 0
\end{equation}
is obtained.

I cannot understand why this result can be derived.

P.S.
The solution of the above conditions is
\begin{equation}
z'(z,\theta) = f(z) + \theta g(z)h(z),\;\;
\theta'(z,\theta) = g(z) + \theta h(z),\;\;
h(z) = \pm[\partial_zf(z) + g(z)\partial_zg(z)]^{1/2},
\end{equation}
where $f(z)$ is ordinary holomorphic function and $g(z)$ is anticommuting holomorphic function.
He says "super-Jacobian", given in (A.2.29) as
\begin{equation}
\delta(dxd\theta) 
= dxd\theta\Big(\sum_i\frac{\delta}{\delta x_i}\delta x_i
 + \frac{\delta}{\delta\theta_j}\delta\theta_j\Big),
\end{equation}

of this transformation is
\begin{equation}
dz'd\theta' = dzd\theta D_\theta\theta'.
\end{equation}
How can I get it?

Answer (score 1):

I think I could solve the problem by myself.
The solution is as follows.

By multiplying $D_\theta$ to $D_\theta\bar\theta' = D_\theta\bar z' = 0$ from the left and use $D_\theta^2 = \partial_z$, we obtain
\begin{equation}
\partial_z\bar\theta' = \partial_z\bar z' = 0.
\end{equation}
By writing the original conditions explicitly,
$(\partial_\theta + \theta\partial_z)\bar\theta'
= (\partial_\theta + \theta\partial_z)\bar z' = 0$.
Eliminating the zero terms by the condition we obtained above, $\theta$ derivative of $\bar\theta'$ and $\bar z'$ is also zero. Summarizing the results and taking the conjugate parts,
\begin{equation}
\partial_{\bar z}\theta' = \partial_{\bar z}z'
= \partial_{\bar\theta}\theta' 
= \partial_{\bar\theta}z' = 0.
\end{equation}